# Sync creating multiple subscription sqlcereplication

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce, merge-replication

I am currently developing a bridge between a database and a sql server database android (sqlite).

To do this, I use a web service and filtered replications with sqlce databases stored on a server IIS 7. To develop this, I used IIS Express on my pc. Everything works fine on my pc but when deployed, replicated databases create a new subscription for each synchronization (while on IIS Express sync works without creating a new subscription), no exceptions are thrown, nothing.

I don't understand why IIS 7 or IIS Express works in a different way to sync databases.

An idea of ​​the reason of the problem?

I use Sql replication ce 3.5 sp2, Sql server 2008 R2 as mother database, IIS7.

I tried to :
-Replicate motherdatabase with a little software on the webserver, it works.
-Use "SqlCeReplication.loadproperties" to find my sqlce database parameters to avoid the creation of the new subscription, it doesn't work.

Other details :
-When it is not syncing for the first time, webservices don't do "repl.AddSubscription(AddOption.CreateDatabase)", I already check that.

Here is the code used to sync :

```
' Define the server, publication, and database names.
Dim repl As SqlCeReplication = Nothing
Try
    repl = New SqlCeReplication
    repl.Publisher = PublisherName
    repl.PublisherLogin = login
    repl.PublisherPassword = password
    repl.PublisherSecurityMode = SecurityType.DBAuthentication
    repl.PublisherDatabase = My.Settings.DBName
    repl.Publication = PublicationName
    repl.InternetUrl = "https://iis.mydomain.com:444/sql/sqlcesa35.dll"
    repl.InternetLogin = "sync"
    repl.InternetPassword = "dfssd"
    repl.Subscriber = "MobileApp - " & login
    repl.SubscriberConnectionString = "Data Source=" & My.Settings.folderDB + "\" + subscriptionName + ".sdf"
    If Not File.Exists(My.Settings.dossierBDD + "\" + subscriptionName + ".sdf") Then
        repl.AddSubscription(AddOption.CreateDatabase)
    End If
    repl.Synchronize()
Catch err As SqlCeException
Finally
    repl.Dispose()
    repl = Nothing
End Try
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the answer... 
I don't really know why but if you want to do merge replication on sqlce, you will need to let the IIS website "Load the user profile" (on the application pool), otherwise subscription are created each time...